# How to roll a log file programmatically in Logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

According to this link: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html (in RollingFileAppender)

It seems to me that Logback provides only a limited way of how to roll a log file.
Based on time, it can roll a log file only in specific interval like once per hour, once
per minute. It does not mention how to roll a log file programmatically which is what I
desire. I need some way to allow users to decide when to roll a log file and the log file
will be used later by the user.

I did some research using Google but found nothing.
Could you please tell me how to roll a log file programmatically

Thank in advance.

Edit: At least I need some way to specify an interval like roll a log file once a ten minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to make your own implementation of the [`TriggeringPolicy`](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/TriggeringPolicy.html). So, make your own implementation (it will check a global variable set by user) and configure the logback with your class.

Not sure about your "Edit:". Sounds like a standard `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` configuration.

Comment: you mentioned that using TimeBasedRollingPolicy will allow me to specify the exact interval. As far as I am concerned I did not find it yet. Could you help point me out?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It has an explicit list for possible periodicity: http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/helper/PeriodicityType.html ... so, you should implement your own `TriggeringPolicy` then. And it looks simple - one method to implement, which will return true each 10 minutes.

Comment: kan, I got it Thank. I am just very surprised to learn why such a very simple requirement like this is not provided out of the box.

Comment: @woraphol.j It's simple, but very unusual. So, it's not in standard implementation.

Answer (score 1):

within (the app start of) `logback.groovy` one could e.g. rollover with arbitrary complex groovy code based on this idea:

```
appender( 'FILE', RollingFileAppender ) {
  ...
  if ( myConditionTrue )
    component.rollover()  // directly rollover on app start / logback.groovy load
}
```

if one would want to rollover based on some checked condition periodically one could do it based on `scan(interval)`:

```
appender( ... ){
  ...
  if ( myConditionTrue )
    component.rollover()
}
scan(30)  // reparse logback.groovy every 30 s if the setup had been changed
```

some nice other things are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374476/logback-manually-call-rollover):

- `SiftingAppender/MDC` usage based on `discriminator:id`, `MDC.put('id','<some-id>')`, `log.info(ClassicConstants.FINALIZE_SESSION_MARKER)`
- directly calling it from within the running app ala `log.getAppender('FILE').rollover()`