# logback manually call rollover

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback

Using logback I would like to start new log every time an async job starts so I need to call rollover manually. But when I try to get appender I get null instead. Below is my config:

```
<configuration scan="true">
    <timestamp key="time" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm"/>
    <logger name="com.my.com.pany" level="DEBUG">
        <appender name="TEST" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>logs/log_TEST_${time}.log</file>
            <triggeringPolicy
                    class="com.my.com.pany.myapp.logging.ManualRollingPolicy">
            </triggeringPolicy>
            <append>true</append>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

I call rollover like this:

```
  ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logF = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.my.com.pany");
        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender = (RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>) logF.getAppender("test");
        appender.rollover();
```

I extended `TimeBasedRollingPolicy<E>` so that my log will start when i trigger async job:

```
@NoAutoStart
public class ManualRollingPolicy<E> extends TimeBasedRollingPolicy<E> {
}
```

Could somone help me with this issue?
EDIT: Upon some further investigation I can see that `LogF` has `appenderList` of size 1 which has my custom `RollingPolicy` properly set. However `name` property of this appender is set to null and I think that is the reason why I can't get it by name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I got a pretty neat workaround which I think someone may find helpful. You can use [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender). "As its name implies, a SiftingAppender can be used to separate (or sift) logging according to a given runtime attribute"

So you configure your appender to take some unique parameter, in my case date of batch job start:

```
<appender name="FULL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>id</key>
            <defaultValue>000000</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>

        <sift>
            <appender name="FULL-${id}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>logs/log_${id}.log</file>
                <append>false</append>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
```

And then you manually call:
`MDC.put("id",id);` in order to start new log and when you are done with this paticular log file you just log a `FINALIZE_SESSION_MARKER` constant:
`logger.info(ClassicConstants.FINALIZE_SESSION_MARKER)`. In my opinion it is flexible enough that it answers the question of manuall rollover.

Answer (score 7):

I have finally figured out how you can do this Programatically.
In case anyone else stumbles upon this question.

to manually rollover :

```
public static void manuallyRolloverLog() {
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger log = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainActivity.class);
    RollingFileAppender file = (RollingFileAppender) log.getAppender("FILE");
    file.rollover();
}
```

The XML Configuration i used is as follows :

```
<configuration>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>AppLog.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>AppLog.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

This will make a SizeBased rolling, and allow you to manually rollover on request.

Comment: I tried adding the call to rollover() in my code and I get an exception:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)' on a null object reference
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.FileFilterUtil.afterLastSlash(Unknown Source)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy.rollover(Unknown Source)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.attemptRollover(Unknown Source)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.rollover(Unknown Source)
        Any ideas?